# First isomorphism theorem: is there a canonical "inverse" map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let's say $N,P$ are $R$-modules, and $\psi:N\to P$ is $R$-linear and surjective.

Knowing that $N/\ker(\psi)\cong P$ ( by the first iso theorem), what can we say about a map $P\to N$? Is there a canonical linear map here? I tried constructing one as follows with no avail:

For each $p\in P$, there is some $n_p\in N$ with $\psi(n_p)=p$. So define the map
$$
G:P\to N,\quad p\mapsto n_p.
$$
This should be well-defined since for any $p\in P$, we picked exactly one corresponding $n_p\in N$. But I am not seeing how to show this is $R$-linear. I'm not even convinced it is. But is there something else we can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely unlikely that this map will be linear. For example, consider $\mathbb Z \longrightarrow \mathbb Z/2$. The only $\mathbb Z$ linear map in the other direction is the $0$ map. The proposed "inverse" as you called it is typically referred to as a section: a map $G: P \longrightarrow N$ such that $\psi \circ G = id$. The $G$ you constructed is therefore a section in the category of sets, but it is very rare that it would be in the category of modules.

However, there is an extremely important class of modules $P$ where this will always hold. These are called projective modules. By definition, we say that a module $P$ is projective precisely if every surjection $N \longrightarrow P$ has a section in the sense I defined above. These are an extremely important class of modules, and I'd strongly recommend reading up on them. Interestingly, you can prove that a module is projective if and only if it is the direct summand of a free module. So in some sense, projective modules are the next best thing to free modules.